# Contacts vs Account.Contacts in SQOL sub query

Tags: soql

Is there any difference in specifying relationship name like `Contacts` and `Account.Contacts` in SOQL subquery?

e.g.

```
SELECT Account.Name, 
       (SELECT Contact.FirstName FROM Account.Contacts) 
FROM Account
```

[salesforce doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)

vs

```
SELECT Name, 
       (SELECT FirstName FROM Contacts) 
FROM Account
```

[Salesforce doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is how much typing you want to do. The system accepts both formats, but returns the exact same results in the exact same format no matter which method you use. So, if you like typing more, you can include the table names in the query (as in the first example). In theory, some really complicated queries might be more self-documenting when using the table names, but it's never necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Both are same. First one is explicity defined and second one not. Both will return same results and query performance will also be same.